# Google Voice Search add to favorites on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, search, voice, favorites

How can i add on chrome, a favorite button than take me directly to Google Voice Search?

I just want to save me the go to google homepage and click into the mic. That will be really useful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a chrome addon that might allow you to do something like that:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/voice-search/hhfkcobomkalfdlmkongnhnhahkmnaad?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon

I haven't used it so wouldn't know how convenient is it.

Comment: that extension is old and also add two mics into the google search box and is not google official